# How I can return a path to a string?

Tags: c#, string, return

I want to ask how i can return a path to a string? i'm having this error message

> '_Default.uploadfile(string,string)': not all code paths return a value

```
private string uploadfile(String filetype, String Uploadfilename)
{
    String csFileUploadName;
    if (filetype == "FiUptrack")
    {
        csFileUploadName = "C:\\MusicStore\\uploads\\promos\\" + Uploadfilename;
    }
    else
    {
        csFileUploadName = "C:\\MusicStore\\uploads\\images\\" + Uploadfilename;
    }        

    try
    {
        FiUptrack.SaveAs(csFileUploadName);
        lblRequired.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        return csFileUploadName.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblRequired.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
  csArtworkupload = uploadfile("Artworkupload", FiUptrack.FileName);
```

csArtworkupload is a string

Answer (score 4):

As the error message clearly states, your method doesn't always return anything.

Specifically, if an exception is thrown, no `return` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That error is because you're not returning across all execution paths in your code - i.e. certain branches will not result in a return.

Try putting this in the end of your code:

```
return csArtworkupload;
```

Comment: how i can return the path in a string?

Comment: Which path? If the path is in the string `csArtworkupload` then the line I provided will do precisely that.

Comment: this on "C:\\MusicStore\\uploads\\images\\" + Uploadfilename;

Comment: Just do `return "C:\\MusicStore\\uploads\\images\\" + Uploadfilename;` - though if this kind of thing is causing you problems, I suggest you read some more C# tutorials before attempting something like this.